# Python онлайн мониторинг Android устройств

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, мониторинг

Хочу реализовать мониторинг устройств(статус, уровень заряда акб и т.д.) на Python.
Для IOS нашел библиотеку [pyicloud](https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud/blob/master/README.rst). Она использует соед. с учетной записью iCloud...

Для Android пока не удалось найти. 
Знаю, что у Google есть сервис "Найти устройство".
Может кто знает какие есть варианты? Если для Python нету, то могу рассмотреть и другие варианты...

Comment: Если вдруг кто будет использовать pyicloud, то помните, что чем чаще будут обращения, тем быстрее разрядится ваше устройство)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще от Google для Python есть библиотека googleapiclient.
Подробнее [тут](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation) и файлы проектов (сэмплы) [тут](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/samples), однако в сэмплах я не нашел информации об устройстве. Может быть вам это удастся.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю... На первый взгляд там не нашел пока :(

Comment: К сожалению, так и не удалось найти :( Когда-то давно я видел в интернете статью, где человек сделал мониторинг устройств на своём сайте, но сейчас не удаётся найти ту статью.